# PHP SQL WHERE IN using implode

Tags: php, sql, arrays, implode, where-in

In file **option-name.php** I have this part of checkbox code:

```
<?php
$query_o_meno = "SELECT meno FROM uctovnictvo GROUP BY meno ORDER BY meno";      
$result_meno  = mysql_query($query_o_meno) or die(mysql_error());ň
?>

<form method="post">

<?php
echo "<strong>Meno:</strong>";
echo "<br />";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_meno)){
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='option_meno[]' value='".$row['meno']."' checked />" . $row['meno'];
 echo "<br />";
    }
?>

<input type="submit" name="Filtrovat" value="Filtrovat" />
</form>
```

The code from **option-name.php** is included into **second** php file by `include 'php/option-name.php' ;`. These **second** php file has also this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM uctovnictvo WHERE meno IN ('" . implode('\', \'', $option_meno) . "')   AND  datum BETWEEN '$date_start' AND '$date_end'  ORDER BY $order";
```

Before I click on button FILTROVAT I have undefined variable `$option_meno` in second php file. How can I define values of `$result_meno` into `$option_meno` and do not have problem is `implode()`?

Thank you

Comment: Did you make sure your include comes AFTER where you define $option_meno? I don't see it in your code sample

Comment: $option_meno is not defined befor I clik FILTROVAT. I dont know how to define it so I dont have problem with implode().

Comment: This question is nothing to do with SQL or `implode()`. You should update it accordingly.

Comment: I'll just put this link http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases_interacting here and let you think on what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks Kguest I hope it can help me.

Comment: You should have a google for SQL injection.

Comment: Miken32 Im new here so I dont understand all what is in that link. If anyone can explain me what should I do I would be happy